# Task.ConfigureAwait(false) in Xamarin - safe to use / recommended to use?

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

Rule of thumb says: if it's not a UI related method, use `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

What if I have a PCL core library which accepts an interface `IUIAccess`.
The view model in the core library then has a method:

```
public Task ViewModelLoginAsync()
{
  bool success = await loginService.ServiceLoginAsync();
  if(!success)
  {
    uiAccess.ShowInfoDialog("Login failed.");
  }
}
```

`IUIAccess` would show a `UIAlertView` on iOS.

My assumption would now be: if I call `ViewModelLoginAsync` from my `UIViewController` I should not configure await to FALSE. It clearly is UI code.
However the call to `ServiceLoginAsync` could use configure await false. Is this correct?
Is it just good practice or really recommended because of performance, memory usage, ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I recommend (as much as possible) *not* to call from the VM into the view. I would prefer to use data binding or a message bus of some kind.

That said, you would not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `ViewModelLoginAsync`, since it needs to resume on the UI context (this is also true if you update via data binding instead of an explicit call). However `ServiceLoginAsync` should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for the reasons I describe in my [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) (primarily performance).