# Xamarin async Method on Main Thread clarification

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

*Does `.ConfigureAwait(false)` always use the thread pool and not the UI thread
or is just a hint?*

This is a question that has bugged me and I haven't heard a definitive answer.

So is it possible even if you do a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` block the main UI thread and when debugging the dreaded

> Skipped 100 frames!!

message?

Comment: One of the best answers you can get: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341155/1771254

Comment: Thanks, that post didn't really answer it. his link to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx Did answer the question.

Comment: Using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` means when that task ends, the following code will not be marshaled back to the calling thread, saving some thread marshalling, which takes time. When `.ConfigureAwait(false)`is not called the default is `.ConfigureAwait(true)` which means "When this task is done, marshal the following code back to the thread this task was called from

Comment: Thanks Leo, put that on the answer. Also the actual Task will it be done on the thread pool?

Comment: yes,i have put it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` means when that task ends, the following code will not be marshaled back to the calling thread, saving some thread marshalling, which takes time. When `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is not called the default is `.ConfigureAwait(true)` which means "When this task is done, marshal the following code back to the thread this task was called from.

As a general rule, every piece of code that is not in a view model and/or that does not need to go back on the main thread should use `ConfigureAwait` `false`.

This is simple, easy and can improve the performance of an application by freeing the UI thread for a little longer.

It is not only a matter or performance but also a matter of avoiding potential deadlocks.

you could read this [document](https://johnthiriet.com/configure-await/#)